# Overwrite css styling in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So in the app.js file, I've imported an style.css file that contains lots of site-wide styling options. But, in a different page(about page) parallax scrolling (using react-spring) doesn't work.
So my question is, can I somehow overwrite app.js styling in aboutpage.js page?

Thank you all!

I removed the style.css from app.js and aboutpage.js worked correctly.

Comment: You could locally scope the about page style to just that component by using CSS modules perhaps...?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App.js` is what your app is rendered on.
So, every page has those imports.

You can use simple logic when the app is mounted to import, or not the `style.css` file using the React-Router.

Here's how you'd do it.

In your `App.js`, you'd no longer `import` at the top, but in a `useEffect`:

```
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname === "/about") {
      console.log("It looks like we're in about, no import.");
    } else {
      console.log("It looks like we are outside of about, importing style.css");
      import("/styles/style.css"); // change the path!
    }
  }, []);
```

Remember to import `useLocation`.

`console.log()` is obviously only there to make it easier to understand the logic and to test it on your side.

Comment: Thank you so much for such quick reply, it worked.

Comment: No problem Kotsias! Do not hesitate to post more questions.